# Clearing ListBox from another Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, function, listbox

I have been stuck on this and don't know what I am doing wrong here. I am trying to clear a `ListBox` from another `Form` via a button.

On my main `Form` where I have the `ListBox` I have this function:

```
public void test()
{
    this.DeviceList.Items.Clear();
}
```

And on the other `Form` where I have my button I have:

```
Form1 mainform = new Form1();
mainform.test();
```

But when I press the button nothing happens. Now if I switch out `this.DeviceList.Items.Clear();` to `MessageBox.Show("test");` that works just fine. But not if I am using `this.DeviceList.Items.Clear();`.

I tried using without `this` but still the same issue.

Comment: Does `Form1`'s constructor have the data you want to clear? In the other hand, are your clearing from the right instance of `Form1`?

Comment: can you try log your events with  `Trace.Write(DeviceList.Items[0]);` because maybe it is working but the UI is not updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code:

```
Form1 mainform = new Form1();
mainform.test();
```

you create a **new** form *don't* `Show` it but clear its `DeviceList`. You should find out an *existing* form, e.g.:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var mainform  = Application
  .OpenForms
  .OfType<Form1>()     //TODO: put the right type if required
  .LastOrDefault();    // if you have several intances, let's take the last one

if (mainform  != null) // if MainForm instance has been found...
  mainform .test();    // ... we clear its DeviceList
```